# How to get kotlin function's caller

Tags: kotlin

With this example:

```
open class Parent {
    fun some():Parent {
        return this;
    }
}

class A : Parent(){
    val name:String? = null;
}
```

But then this code results in an error:

```
val a = A().some().some()
a.name // ERROR
```

**EDITOR NOTE:**  *based on comments of the author to answers below, the question is NOT about referencing `a.name` but really is about something like "how do I get the instance of the class or its name that first started the chain of method calls".  Read all comments below until the OP edits this for clarity.*

> my final goal is to return caller's type and can call this caller's instance property, no more as , no more override, any idea?

Comment: I cleaned up the question and added the open keyword you mentioned in a comment was already there, so people do not miscontrue what the problem might be

Comment: Based on your comments you are not saying what your actual question is.  You are making it look like you have a problem referencing a property of class `A` but that is not what you are trying to do at all, you should update the question based on your comments.  I added an editors note which you should remove and replace with a clarifying message of your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actially your example is working(if you add `open` keyword because all classes in Kotlin are final by default:

A.kt

```
 open class A {
    fun some(): A {
        return this
    }
 }
```

B.kt

```
 class B : A() {
     val test = "test"
 }
```

And usage

```
val tmpB = (B().some().some() as B)
val test = tmpB.test
```

Edited:
It because function some() return parent class which doesn't have child class property. So you need to cast it to child class.(Update code)

Comment: i forgot add open ,sorry, but it won't work ,i tried.

Comment: @junk Strange. Because I've just compiled and run this code. What is your kotlin version and plugin?

Comment: version : 1.1.1-release  2016.1.1 IDEA

Comment: any idea about this?

Comment: No ideas...Try update kotlin then clean and rebuild project.

Comment: yeah i know this now  ,but new question is here: function some() return :A type, but this can't get B's property,  i will update my question

Comment: but this does not do really what you are asking @junk and only just happens to work for the contrived case.

Answer (score 1):

Just like [java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4065546/6521116), you can use `stackTrace`'s `getMethodName()`. Refer to the [kotlin doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/stack-trace.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
open class Parent{
    open fun foo(): Parent {
        return this;
    }
}
```

This is your `Parent` class. `Parent` class has a method named `foo()`.  `foo()` is a method of class A which will return the instance of it's own class. We must have to open the class and method because by default their visibility modifier is final.

```
class A : Parent() {
    override fun foo(): A { return this }
}
```

This is a class named `A` which extends `Parent` class. `foo()` is a method of class A which will return the instance of it's own class.

We will call it like this:

```
var a = A().foo().foo()
```

Comment: it's ok but, how to use A().foo().foo() ,foo() is parent class's method.

Comment: if i won't override function ,is there any way to realize this?

Comment: We have to override because the method named foo() is present in both Parent and Child class.

Comment: but when i don't override , A().foo() is worked ,and return A's entity, but cant continue use any function on this entity ,why?

Comment: If you use a different name, then you didn't face any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your class always return `Parent` instance. This class do not have any field with the name `name`. To do that you have 2 ways:

The first:

```
open class Parent{
    fun some():Parent{
        return this
    }
}

class A :Parent(){
    val name:String? = null
}

fun main() {
    val a = (A().some().some() as A)
    a.name = "";
}
```

The second:

```
open class Parent{
    open fun some():Parent{
        return this
    }
}

class A :Parent(){
    override fun some():A {
        return this
    }

    val name:String? = null
}

fun main() {
    val a = A().some().some()
    a.name = "";
}
```

Comment: I think the second solution's better in your case @junk.

Comment: my final goal is to return caller's type and can call this caller's instance property, no more as , no more  override, any idea?

Comment: No! You can't do that.

Comment: @junk should update the question to reflect what is being asked, it is misleading as written now

Answer (score -2):

i have know how to do this:

@Avijit Karmakar

@Trần Đức Tâm

use ***inline function***

```
 inline fun <reified T:Any> some(sql: String):T {

        return this as T ;
    }
```